# Excel vba format and find issues

Tags: excel, vba

I have some very simple code and I want to find the rows in column D where the %-sign is. So `i` should be 4 (obviously), but I don't know how to overcome the run time error 91.

So many thanks in advance for your hints.

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim i As Integer

a = 4
b = 5

Worksheets(1).Range("D4") = (a / b) * 100
Worksheets(1).Range("D4").NumberFormat = "0.00\%"

' run time error 91 occures in the following line    
i = Worksheets(1).Range("D:D").Find(What:="%", After:=Range("D1"), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row
' result of i
Range("A1")=i
```

Comment: You need to add the `LookIn:=xlValues` argument to the Find method call.

Comment: When using `Find()`, always set a range to the return value, and check that's not `Nothing` before (eg) trying to access its `Row`.  So for example `Set f = Worksheets(1).Range("D:D").Find(...):  If Not f Is Nothing Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Find the Top-Most Cell Formatted As a Percentage in a Column

... or contains the percentage sign.

- Read the comments by (credits also go to) Rory and Tim Williams and memorize them.

**(Workbook and) Worksheet Variable**

```vb
Sub Test()
    
    Dim a As Long: a = 4
    Dim b As Long: b = 5

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

    ws.Range("D4").Value = (a / b) * 100
    ws.Range("D4").NumberFormat = "0.00\%"
    
    Dim cell As Range: Set cell = ws.Range("D:D").Find(What:="%", _
        After:=ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

    If cell Is Nothing Then
        ws.Range("A1").Value = ""
        MsgBox "Could not find """ & "%" & """ in column D.", vbCritical
    Else
        ws.Range("A1").Value = cell.Row
        MsgBox "Found """ & "%" & """ in cell """ & cell.Address(0, 0) & """.", _
            vbInformation
    End If

End Sub
```

**The `With` Statement**

```vb
Sub TestWith()
    
    Dim a As Long: a = 4
    Dim b As Long: b = 5
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        
        .Range("D4").Value = (a / b) * 100
        .Range("D4").NumberFormat = "0.00\%"
        
        Dim cell As Range: Set cell = .Range("D:D").Find(What:="%", _
            After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    
        If cell Is Nothing Then
            .Range("A1").Value = ""
        Else
            .Range("A1").Value = cell.Row
        End If
            
    End With

End Sub
```